# View background shrinks when view is addressed or animated

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

I can not find why the background of my subview shrinks toward the upper left corner of the subview the first time I move it or animate it.  (not sure if it is technically a 'subview' since the object I dragged on to my main view was labeled 'View')

For this example, I will provide an animated example so that you can see what is going on easier.

Here are my .h entries (2 objects, a button and a view)

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *floatPad;
- (IBAction)toggleButton:(UIButton *)sender;
```

For this example (iPad) the view is located at (20, 800) with a size of (728, 186).  I also set the background to light grey in the Interface Builder to show what's going on better.

The button toggles the view on and off the screen, sliding (via animation code) off and on through the bottom of the screen.

Here are my .m entries (1 BOOL, 1 UIColor, plus the 'viewDidLoad' and 'toggleButton' code)

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL floatPadVisible;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIColor* redBackground;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize floatPad;
@synthesize floatPadVisible;
@synthesize redBackground;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
floatPadVisible:YES;
    redBackground = [UIColor colorWithRed:179/255.0 green:1/255.0 blue:54/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)toggleButton:(UIButton *)sender {

if (floatPadVisible) { //is floatPadVisible BOOL set to YES
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"floatPad" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [floatPad setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 1004, 584, 145)];
    [floatPad setBackgroundColor:redBackground];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    floatPadVisible = NO;
    }
else {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"floatPad" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [floatPad setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 800, 584, 145)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    floatPadVisible = YES;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the first time you hit the toggle button, the view doesn't move, only the background shrinks.  I say shrinks, because you can still the the 20 point space on the left side of the view.  If you put an object inside the view, it doesn't move, which tells me the view isn't shrinking, only the background.  After the first 'toggle' the button operates as expected.  I added the background change color code to show that the first toggle never calls the animation code, evident by the fact that the background doesn't change color until the second toggle.

Comment: You know, one day I'm going to write a language that's completely incompatible with Xcode called Xcode just to piss people off.  Until then, restrict the [Xcode] tag to IDE-related questions, not language-related questions.

Comment: I get it now.  It did feel redundant.  So xcode tag only for issues or questions about the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how often this happens, but I can answer my own question after staring at this problem for weeks.  If you look at the top where I describe the added view, I give it the dimensions (728, 186).  But my own animation code shrinks the box to (584, 145).

As for why the first time hitting the toggle button doesn't change the background, it's because I believed I was setting the 'floatPadVisible' flag to YES with the syntax:

```
floatPadVisible:YES;
```

When in fact it wasn't and the first time through the method, it runs through the not visible code.